# Sending Data from Android App to Php

Tags: php, android, wamp, wampserver

I have a php form running in WAMP server on a local network ... But when I try to run that file it gives me the error in the screenshot. I am trying to send data from my Android app to Php form . Also my Android app crashes on pressing the "Send" Button

I have made sure :

1. Both WAMP and Android app are on the same network
2. Also I tried to directly access the URL from android browser and it brings up the page , so URL should not be a trouble
3. I have tried using a real device and its the same error .
4. Also I have added INTERNET permission in Android Manifest!

[image]

PHP code :

```
<?php
// get the "message" variable from the post request
// this is the data coming from the Android app
$message=$_POST["message"]; 
// specify the file where we will save the contents of the variable message
$filename="androidmessages.html";
// write (append) the data to the file
file_put_contents($filename,$message."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
// load the contents of the file to a variable
$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);
// display the contents of the variable (which has the contents of the file)
echo $androidmessages;
?>
```

And here is the Android App code :

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);        

        // make message text field object
        msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
        // make send button object
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

    }

    // this is the function that gets called when you click the button
    public void send(View v)
    {
        // get the message from the message text box
        String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  

        // make sure the fields are not empty
        if (msg.length()>0)
        {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.0.40/yourPhpScript.php");
         try {
           List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           httpclient.execute(httppost);
           msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box
         } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         } catch (IOException e) {
             // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         }

        }
        else
        {
            // display message if text fields are empty
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"All field are required",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Edit 1 : Here is the LogCat as requested for the original code

```
02-10 23:44:06.570: D/dalvikvm(1919): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on)
02-10 23:44:06.720: D/dalvikvm(1919): GC_CONCURRENT freed 73K, 10% free 2785K/3092K, paused 13ms+0ms, total 16ms
02-10 23:44:07.550: D/gralloc_goldfish(1919): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
02-10 23:44:17.428: D/AndroidRuntime(1919): Shutting down VM
02-10 23:44:17.428: W/dalvikvm(1919): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f3e648)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     ... 11 more
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     at com.diwesh.helloworldactivity.HelloWorldActivity.send(HelloWorldActivity.java:73)
02-10 23:44:17.428: E/AndroidRuntime(1919):     ... 14 more
```

Edit 2: LogCat after change from recommended code

```
02-11 19:28:35.991: D/AndroidRuntime(1945): Shutting down VM
02-11 19:28:35.991: W/dalvikvm(1945): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xb0f16648)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3633)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3628)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     ... 11 more
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1133)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     at com.diwesh.helloworldactivity.HelloWorldActivity.send(HelloWorldActivity.java:93)
02-11 19:28:35.991: E/AndroidRuntime(1945):     ... 14 more
```

Comment: Use `AsyncTask` for posting data to server

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK : Thanks for the advice . But I would like to know where I am going wrong here

Comment: if app is crashing then add logcat result with question to check where is problem

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work for you, change http request in your android code to this,

```
  private void startHttpRequest()
  {
    try
    {
       new Thread(new Runnable() 
       {
           public void run() 
           {

             // get the message from the message text box
             String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();  

             // make sure the fields are not empty
             if (msg.length()>0)
             {
               HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
               HttpPost httppost = new                   HttpPost("http://192.168.0.40/yourPhpScript.php");
               try 
               {
                 StringEntity se = new StringEntity("id=12345&message="+msg);
                 httppost.setEntity(se);
                 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                 msgTextField.setText(""); // clear text box

               StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
               if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
               {
                 ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                 response.getEntity().writeTo(out);

                //* this should be the return from your php script  $androidmessages
                 String responseString = out.toString(); 
                 out.close();
               }
               } 
               catch (ClientProtocolException e) 
               {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               } 
               catch (IOException e) {
                   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               }
             }
           }
       }).start();

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
    }
  }
```

then change the code in your php script to this,

```
<?php
// get the "message" variable from the post request
// this is the data coming from the Android app
$id=$_REQUEST["id"]; 
$message=$_REQUEST["message"]; 
// specify the file where we will save the contents of the variable message
$filename="androidmessages.html";
// write (append) the data to the file
file_put_contents($filename,$message."<br />",FILE_APPEND);
// load the contents of the file to a variable
$androidmessages=file_get_contents($filename);
// display the contents of the variable (which has the contents of the file)
echo $androidmessages;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks I am trying your code , but what library I need to import to make "response.getStatusLine()" work .... It says response cannot be resolved

Comment: Sorry for the delay, my answer is missing on item let me fix it and that should answer your question

Comment: Thanks I'll check it and get back to you ... Also should I create a file with the name "androidmessages.html" in the same directory ? or will it create for me if in case it doesn't find one ? Also If I create it do I need to have some html code inside it or save it just blank ?

Comment: The app still crashes because the http request code need to run in a thread, it can not run on the main thread.  I will modify the example to include how to put the code inside a thread.  About your first question, file_put_content will create the file if it does not exist, it need to be in the same directory of the php code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be sure that your PHP script is correct.
Then, remove the 'onClick' in the XML configuration for the button.
Use the code below. It'll work

```
public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity {

    Button sendButton;

    EditText msgTextField;

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // load the layout
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // make message text field object
        msgTextField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.msgTextField);
        // make send button object
        sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sendButton);

        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // check for empty message
                if (msgTextField.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
                    new sendMessage().execute();
                } else {
                    // display message if text fields are empty
                    Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this, "All field are required", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    private class sendMessage extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(HelloWorldActivity.this);
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setMessage("Sending Message...");
            dialog.setCancelable(false);
            dialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {


            // get the message from the message text box
            String msg = msgTextField.getText().toString();

            // desired URL
            final String mURL = "http://192.168.0.40/yourPhpScript.php";

            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(mURL);
            HttpResponse response;

            // Add data
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", "12345"));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("message", msg));


            try {
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
                response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                String responseBody = EntityUtils
                        .toString(response.getEntity());
                Log.d("Http Post Response:", responseBody);

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            dialog.dismiss();

            // Toast user for a successful operation
            Toast.makeText(HelloWorldActivity.this, "Message sent successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            // clear text box
            msgTextField.setText("");

        }
    }


}
```